# How to pass username and password along with json datasource URL in jasper

Tags: json, jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to pass username and password along with JSON datasource URL in jasper if I am using JSON datasource in subreport to get some JSON data using that URL?

In main report:

```
<subreport>
    ...
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource("http://172.16.94.11:8081/api/v1/colorways/32a71f8d-15d67699834-UFXQ1MzCf...", "")]]></dataSourceExpression>
</subreport>
```

To access URL we need to give username password, if I pass username password like below directly in browser it works, but through JasperReports Server it gives HTTP 201 error:
http://username:pasword@172.16.94.11:8081/api/v1/colorways/32a71f8d-15d6...

I am using datasource for subreport like below:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource("http://172.16.94.11:8081/api/v1/colorways/32a71f8d-15d67699834-UFXQ1MzCfpneWo1Vnqn-nQ/", "")
```

Comment: What version of JasperReports Server are you using?

Comment: jasperserver 6.4.3

Comment: Did you check out any of these([1](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1107291/traversing-json-output-rest-api-datasource) or [2](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/1111291/web-service-using-json-data-adapter-passing-http-parameters-url-body-through)) community answers?

Comment: yes narcis , i checked , it works if json url dont have username password authentication, but if have to access using usernm passwd, it is not working, how to pass username password through url?

Comment: any idea is helpful..

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally, created an adapter and exported as a xml , then i added that xml as  datasource for subreport by adding this below argument:

its working properly.

Comment: i think you forgot to add the argument you added in the json. Would you please add that here?